Bellum Gallicum I Specific Translation
"Gallia est omnis divisa in partes tres, quarum unam incolunt Belgae, aliam Aquitani, tertiam qui ipsorum lingua Celtae, nostra Galli appellantur."
In the first part of the sentence "Gallia est omnis" how would you translate it because it sounds really weird considering the translation of a Genitive omnis? So considering the context and the syntax of the clause, I found myself translating it as,"Gaul, as a whole.." but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Does the annotated translation of that passage at https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/order-words help?

omnis here is nominative, not genitive.

That's actually very similar for how the phrase is translated in Latin for Dummies,  which has as its translation:-  Gaul was, on the whole, divided into three parts.

Is it acceptable to translate the beginning as: "All of Gaul is divided into three parts..."? Sounds simpler, but I wonder if it is equivalent.

The translation given in WheelCocks Latin for
   Gallia est omnis divisa in partes tres

is
   The whole of Gaul has been(is) divided into three parts

omnis rather than only being the genitive form of the adjective, omnis can also be the nominative singular masculine or feminine adjectival form, and here agrees with Gallia.
Dictionary etymologique de la langue latine states totus and omnis are often in the singular used one for the other.
In other words omnis in this sense, is taking on the meaning, 'the whole', for 'Gallia omnis' literally 'whole Gaul'. English, rather than how Latin uses the adjective, has a different means of expression, and in English its possible to say, the whole of something. In english, we say the whole country (generic word for country), but instead say the whole of (specific country), such as the whole of Gaul.
There are different ways this phrase can be translated into English, because there are different ways of saying the same thing.
